$x^3y^2z$ achieves maximum value under what conditions?
Given that $x,y,z \geq 0$, it is given that $x^3y^2z$ achieves its maximum value under the conditions that 6x+4y+z=1 and $xyz = \frac{m}{n}$. Given $gcd(m,n)=1$ and $m$ and $n$ are integers. What is m+n?
By using AM GM inequality, I was getting
$$
\frac{6x+4y}{10} \geq (x^6y^4)^\frac{1}{10}
$$
Multiplying both sides by $z^\frac{1}{5}$, rearranging, and substituting $6x+4y$ with $1-z$, I got
$$
\frac{z(1-z)^5}{10^5} \geq x^3y^2z
$$
Please help

It is a standard practice on MSE that you give the name (and year) of the contest when asking contest-math tagged problems. There are a few reasons for this. Hopefully it is an easy edit.

It is not a previous year question though. It is in one of the sample papers provided by the people who organize the contest. This question was in  sample paper F for the South East Asian Math Olympiad(SEAMO) this year

I would take the AM GM: $1=2x+2x+2x+2y+2y+z\geqslant 6\sqrt[6]{32\,x^3y^2z} $ to get $$\implies x^3y^2z\leqslant \frac1{6^6\cdot 32}$$
This would give the maximum, as $x=y=\frac1{12}, z=\frac16$ achieves this value. Thus $xyz$ and hence $m+n$ can be got.

The question is weirdly phrased isn't it? Under the conditions of $6x+4y+z=1$ and $xyz = m/n$, we can always find $(x, y, z)$ such that $x^3y^2z$ is maximized. So what's unique about this particular $(m, n)$ that you found? $\quad$ You're answering the question of "Under the condition that $6x+4y+z = 1$, when we maximize $x^3y^2z$, what is the value of $xyz$? $\quad$ In fact, given $x, y, z \geq 0$, then $x^3y^2z$ never achieves its maximum.

@CalvinLin Perhaps the question isn't phrased right, but too many such questions these days seem to be of the form find the answer in form $m/n$ - which is what I assumed.  In fact if one interprets $xyz=m/n$ also as a condition of the problem itself, then any value of $m/n  \leqslant 1/(144*12)$ should work; so that seems to be the wrong interpretation.

I may confirm the result of Macavity. Since I still have not understood AM/GM I approached the problem using derivatives.
